# SmallStep step-ca and Traefik - could not connect to validation target

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to set up a Let's Encrypt type service in a private network with the Smallstep step-ca and traefik.
And I'm stuck because step-ca fails to validate the certificate request from traefik..

Here is what I have done so far.

I launched a step-ca service in a docker container like explained in [this documentation](https://smallstep.com/docs/tutorials/docker-tls-certificate-authority)  on a server with IP "172.16.4.5". I've also followed [this documentation to add the acme entry point](https://smallstep.com/docs/tutorials/acme-challenge).

On another server "172.16.4.4", I launched a docker-compose configuration with Traefik 2.4 and a "whoami" service (Like here [the official example](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/user-guides/docker-compose/acme-tls/)).

All internal domains names are served by a private DNS Server. And each server resolved domain name without problem.

The server and the step-ca container can reach the server 172.16.4.4 on port 80 and 443. The server 172.16.4.4 and the traefik container can reach the 172.16.4.5. I installed in traefik container the root certificate made with step-ca during its initialization.

I've set up traefik to use TSL challenge. Traefik initialise the challenge and, I don't know why the step-ca raise an error
**{"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection","detail":"The server
could not connect to validation target"}}**

Below the full error raised by step-ca :

```
INFO[0126]     duration=63.427116ms duration-ns=63427116 fields.time="2021-07-13T09:55:33Z" method=POST name=ca nonce=XX path=/acme/company.int/authz/XX protocol=HTTP/1.1 referer= remote-address=172.16.4.4 request-id=xx response="{\"identifier\":{\"type\":\"dns\",\"value\":\"whoami.company.int\"},\"status\":\"pending\",\"challenges\":[{\"type\":\"dns-01\",\"status\":\"pending\",\"token\":\"XX\",\"url\":\"https://acme.company.int:9000/acme/company.int/challenge/XX/XX\"},{\"type\":\"http-01\",\"status\":\"pending\",\"token\":\"XX\",\"url\":\"https://acme.company.int:9000/acme/company.int/challenge/XX/XX\"},{\"type\":\"tls-alpn-01\",\"status\":\"pending\",\"token\":\"XX\",\"url\":\"https://acme.company.int:9000/acme/company.int/challenge/XX/XX\",\"error\":{\"type\":\"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection\",\"detail\":\"The server could not validation target\"}}],\"wildcard\":false,\"expires\":\"2021-07-14T09:54:24Z\"}" size=872 status=200 user-agent="containous-traefik/2.4.8 xenolf-acme/4.3.1 (release; linux; amd64)" user-id=
```

Here the Traefik config.toml

```
[api]
  insecure = true
  dashboard = true
  debug = true

[certificatesResolvers]
  [certificatesResolvers.myresolver]
    [certificatesResolvers.myresolver.acme]
      caServer = "https://acme.compagny.int:9000/acme/company.int/directory"
      email = "dude@mailthings.dn"
      storage = "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
      [certificatesResolvers.myresolver.acme.tlsChallenge]

[providers]
  [providers.docker]
    watch = true
    network = "traefik_webgateway"
    swarmmode = false
    exposedbydefault = false
  [providers.file]
    filename = "traefik.toml"
    directory = "/etc/traefik"
```

Here the /home/step/config/ca.json for step-ca service:

```
{
    "root": "/home/step/certs/root_ca.crt",
    "federatedRoots": [],
    "crt": "/home/step/certs/intermediate_ca.crt",
    "key": "/home/step/secrets/intermediate_ca_key",
    "address": ":9000",
    "insecureAddress": "",
    "dnsNames": [
        "acme.company.int"
    ],
    "authority": {
        "provisioners": [
            {
                "type": "JWK",
                // [...]
                },
                "encryptedKey": "xxx"
            },
            {
                "type": "ACME",
                "name": "company.int",
                "forceCN": true,
                "claims": {
                    "maxTLSCertDuration": "2160h0m0s",
                    "defaultTLSCertDuration": "2160h0m0s"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "ACME",
                "name": "acme"
            }
        ],
        "template": {},
        "backdate": "1m0s"
    },
    "tls": {
        "cipherSuites": [
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
        ],
        "minVersion": 1.2,
        "maxVersion": 1.3,
        "renegotiation": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a parameter issue.

I used to start the step-ca service with the parameter `--resolver` with the IP of the DNS server. But you need to add the port of the DNS server or setp-ca will fail to lookup the domain name.

So the answer of my probleme is jsut to add `:53` at the end of the IP, like this

```
step-ca --resolver="10.14.2.2:53"
```

Comment: My understanding is that you run step-ca in a Docker container, so how are you starting step-ca with the custom parameter? Have you modified the original image? I would be grateful if you would elaborate the explanation of the solution a little, I am having the same problem and maybe someone else stumbles upon it later and it would certainly be helpful.